# How do I log in to kubernetes-cockpit UI if .kube/config contains a token instead of an account?

Tags: kubernetes

Numerous forum posts and documentations specify extracting login info for the Kubernetes install from ~/.kube/config.

The problem I found: mine doesn't have a proper user account, it specifies a name and a token.

How do I get the account name so I can use the kubernetes-cockpit UI? Surprisingly there appears to be nothing on that topic - what to do if the config doesn't contain an account.

Comment: Did you find out how?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you use Cockpit.
According to [cockpit official page](http://cockpit-project.org/guide/latest/feature-kubernetes.html):

Used in a standard cockpit session:

> If a user is able to use kubectl successfully when at their shell terminal, then that same user will able to use Kubernetes dashboard when logged into Cockpit

I suppose this is your scenario, so if you didn't change default settings, the cockpit will look for .kube/config itself, i.e. you should be able to login without specifying your account.

Comment: It at least doesn't for minikube setups.